# qplot, axis labels and loops

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following text file:trial2.txt
 there are over 750 data-frames with over 60 rows. 
I am including a subset of the data:

```
status           cst      Hydroxycotinine     A1_2_propanediol      Bacillus 
Smoker           II, lacto      .023                .234            .234
Smoker           I, lacto       .042                .324            .234
Smoker           III lact       .234                .234            .234
Smoker           II, Lacto      .234                .987            .987
Non smoker       II, Lacto      .533                .987            .234
Non smoker       I, lacto       .234                .342            .972
Non smoker       III, lacto     .782                .234            .897
```

The following is the code I have been using to generate the graph that I want, unfortunately, I haven't been able to loop through the data-frames while maintaining the variable name: I.e., here is my code to generate the graph when I specifically name the variable I want plotted:

```
require(ggplot2)
trial2<-read.table("pl01.txt",header=TRUE,na.strings='',sep='\t')
 qplot(smoking_status,hydroxycotinine,data=trial2,geom="boxplot")+xlab("")+facet_grid(.~cst,scales="free",space="free")+theme_bw()
```

I cannot figure out how to loop through my data-frames while still achieving the column name in the output: 
The code here:

```
    outputs<-(lapply(trial2[3:5],function(x)qplot(smoking_status,trial2$x,data=trial2,geom="boxplot")+xlab("")+facet_grid(.~cst,scales="free",space="free")+theme_bw()))
    outputs
```

outputs the graphs that I want, but loses the name of the variable I'm interested in

I appreciate any suggestions on how to streamline this, or better produce the results that I want. I realize my code is probably not the most efficient. I have also tried melting my data and several other helpful suggestions but but none have fit my needs upon modifying my code.

I would post pictures of my graphs but I can't post pictures yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qplot(...)` is meant as an easy-to-use wrapper for the more complete `ggplot` functions. I'd recommend you abandon it and dive into the full `ggplot` feature-set. Here is one way to do this (only one of the plots reproduced here):

```
library(ggplot2)
plot.col <- function(col) {             # col is the column **name**
  ggplot(trial2, aes(x=status))+
    geom_boxplot(aes_string(y=col))+    # note use of aes_atring(...)
    xlab("")+
    facet_grid(.~cst,scales="free",space="free")+
    theme_bw()
}
lapply(names(trial2)[3:5],plot.col)
```

[image]

The key is the use of `aes_string(...)` with the *name* of the column you want for `y`.